# How to combine jQuery Form Plugin with Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, symfony

Using Symfony2 and jQuery I am trying to develop a form with several fields, one of them `input type="file"`

I have been recommended to use [this framework: jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#faq)

It is working: I am receiving in my PHP Action in the Controller all the fields, including the file typed one.

Has anyone combined this with Symfony2. In other words: what do I do with what I get from the form to save the file in the file system?

I'd like to implement something like [what is officially documented in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html). But... how to do it?

If I go $this->get('request') -> get("form_image"), I get the name of the file. From that point on, I know how to handle the database stuff, but I need to know what to do with the physic file itself (how to save it into file system).

Any clue?

Thanks in advance

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html

Answer (score 0):

If you got only file name but not the file try to make your `<form>` tag in twig template to look like below:

```
<form action="#" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
```

I think that you're missing the `enctype` and form is sending only post data without the files.

### UPDATE

if you have the enctype show me what you got under:

```
// retrieves an instance of UploadedFile identified by foo
$request->files->get('form_image');
```

From documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony

Comment: This is the heading of my form: <form id="form_question" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ path('_save_question') }}" method="post">